# Rack::Cache/Rack::Etag 304

Tags: ruby, http, caching, rack

I use Rack:Etag to genereate proper etag values based on the response from the server and for development I use Rack::Cache to verify that that caching I expect to happen really does

But i have a slight predicament:

I send a request and get these headers back

```
Age →0
Cache-Control →public, max-age=10
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →4895
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 02 Oct 2013 06:55:42 GMT
ETag →"dd65de99f4ce58f9de42992c4e263e80"
Server →thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
X-Content-Digest →0879e41b0d8e9b351f517dd46823095e0e99abd8
X-Rack-Cache →stale, invalid, store
```

If i after 11 seconds send a new request with If-None-Match=dd65de99f4ce58f9de42992c4e263e80 then i expect to get a 304 but always get 200 with the above headers.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be due to `max-age` directive being set to 10

> When the max-age cache-control directive is present in a cached response, the response is stale if its current age is greater than the age value given (in seconds) at the time of a new request for that resource.

Although, did you already know that?  As you tried after 11 secs!

Comment: That I already knew but I thought if when the cache was stale and made a fresh request it would compare etag and give 304 if etag generated matched If-None-Match. But here my knowlegde is very limited :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution was to load the rack middleware as follows for coorect chaining

```
use Rack::Cache
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
```

And also send If-None-Match with "" around hash, which i think seems pretty fragile